# in R, save a shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile

I would like to save a shapefile after a manipulation.

First, I read my object

```
map<-readOGR("C:/MAPS","33SEE250GC_SIR")
```

After this, I subset my shapefile:

```
test <- fortify(map, region="CD_GEOCODI")
test<- subset(test, -43.41<long & long < -43.1 & - 23.05<lat & lat< -22.79)
```

I get the corresponding id's of this subset

```
ids<- unique(test$id)
map2<-  map[map$CD_GEOCODI %in% ids ,]
```

When I plot the map2, it is all right. But, when I try to save this shapefile, somethinh is wrong

```
writeOGR(map2, dsn = "C:/MAPS" , layer = "nameofmynewmap")
```

> Error in match(driver, drvs$name) :
> argument "driver" is missing, with no default

I don't know how to get the drive. Some solution?

Comment: You need to pass in the driver argument? driver="ESRI Shapefile" there are examples in the documentation ?writeOGR.  http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgdal/docs/writeOGR

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that your `map2`object is no longer a shapefile and therefore you cannot save it as a shapefile. The `fortify` command converts the data slot of the shape file (`map@data`) to data.frame object to be used for mapping purposes. `ggplot2` cannot handle objects of class sp (spatial polygon i.e. shape files). I'm assuming you want to save this 'reduced' or 'subsetted' data. What you need to do is the following:

```
  library(rgdal)
  library(dplyr)

  map <- readOGR("C:/MAPS","33SEE250GC_SIR") 
  map <- subset(world, LON>-43.41 | LON < -43.1 & LAT>- 23.05 | LAT< -22.79)

  writeOGR(map, ".", "filename", 
           driver = "ESRI Shapefile") #also you were missing the driver argument
```